# Extract word infront of certain character RegEx Rstudio

Tags: r, regex, string, extract

I have this word, `"sam buy expensive toys as 125898652"`.
I would like to extract the word after "as", which is "125898652".

I'm using

```
(?<=as\s)+[^\s]+
```

I've tried it on [https://regex101.com/r/NaWAl1/1](http://regex101) and it works pretty well.
when i execute it on R it returning error as

```
Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(?<='as'\s"
```

So I modify it to

```
(?<='CR'\s)+[^\s]+
```

It returning different error as :

```
Error in stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
  Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX)
```

Can someone please explain it to me why regex different in R and how to make it works. Thank you so much

Comment: `stringi::stri_extract_first_regex("sam buy expensive toys as 125898652","(?<=as\\s)[^\\s]+")` works well for your case. Do not quantify lookarounds, they are zero-width assertions. And use double backslashes in string literals to define literal backslashes.

Comment: i've used double backslash too for each of the double blackslash there but it still doesnt work

Comment: [`(?<=as\s)+[^\s]+` works well](https://rextester.com/LJF82742)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sub`

```
sub(".*as\\s(\\w+).*", "\\1", "sam buy expensive toys as 125898652")
#[1] "125898652"
```

Or lookbehind regex

```
stringr::str_extract("sam buy expensive toys as 125898652", "(?<=as\\s)\\w+")
#[1] "125898652"
```

---

For words which has `,` in it and may have decimal places we can do

```
x <- "sam buy expensive toys as 128984,45697.00"
sub(".*as\\s(\\d+\\.?\\d+).*", "\\1",gsub(',', '', x))
#[1] "12898445697.00"
```

Comment: the first one amazingly work well, but it not returning the number after . or ,

Comment: @yuliansen Can you share an example ?

Comment: sam buy expensive toys as 128984,45697.00 it only returns 128984. thank you so much for your response

Comment: so will this work ? `sub(".*as\\s(\\d+\\.?\\d+).*", "\\1",gsub(',', '', x))` where `x` is your string.

Comment: i dont know how to thank you so much but you really help me. i will dig into sub and gsub later. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

With base R,  given string `s <- "sam buy expensive toys as 125898652"`, you can use `gsub()` or `strsplit()`:

```
> gsub(".*?as\\s","",s)
[1] "125898652
```

or

```
> unlist(strsplit(s,split = "(?<=as\\s)",perl = T))[2]
[1] "125898652"
```